# How to check if a string contains anything else than whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How can I check if there is text in a string in python or just whitespace?

Example:

`"    "` should return `False`

`"test"` should return `True`

`"tes t "` should return `True`

Comment: See [`isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace)

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
teststring = "   "
print(teststring.isspace())

# True
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.strip()` function will remove any leading or trailing space from you string.

Then you can easily check what you want by checking the length of the new string.

```
>>> my_str_with_space = ' \r\n   string   \r\n   '
>>> my_str_with_space
' \r\n   string   \r\n   '
>>> my_str = my_str_with_space.strip()
>>> my_str
'string'
```

So create a simple function to check if string is empty or not by checking the string length.

```
>>> def str_not_empty(s):
...     return bool(len(s))
```

Then use it.

```
>>> str_not_empty(my_str)
True
>>> str_empty = ''
>>> str_not_empty(str_empty)
False
```

(The function is optional, but it was useful for the example)